# SPI access via C# .NET Core console app

Tags: spi, c#, lcd

I do not have much experience with C# or Linux/Raspbian so would like some advice/guidance please.

Basically I need to write a C# .NET Core console app which will run on a Raspberry Pi Compute 3 module (running Raspbian) allowing text to be written to an LCD connected via SPI (the display is of type ST7565R).

I have written a basic program in C on the Pi to print "Hello World" to the LCD via SPI (using the BCM2835 library from https://www.airspayce.com/mikem/bcm2835/).

I have written and built a standalone C# .Net Core 'Hello World' console app which runs on the Pi.

I want to write "Hello World" to the LCD from within the .NET Core app but I really don't have a clue how to approach it.

Any help will be appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> Copy your app, i.e. whole publish directory mentioned above, to the
>   Raspberry Pi and execute run ./helloworld to see Hello World! from
>   .NET Core running on your Pi! (make sure you chmod 755 ./helloworld)

Source: [Github - RaspberryPiInstructions](https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/samples/RaspberryPiInstructions.md#linux)

Basically, you just have to have the application files (.dlls and all assets, images etc) on your raspberry pi, and then simply tell the console to "open" the file/application.